# Menu active in different action method in yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to make a menu is active when open using a method and another method in a controller. I use this code but the result is the menu is not active. What's the problem?

```
[
      'label'   => 'Sejarah Pengambilan',
      'url'     => ['/paket/index-history'],
      'active'  => in_array(Yii::$app->controller->id, ['index-history', 'index-search']),
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking for action ('index-history', 'index-search') and not for controller

se for action you should use `$this->context->action->id`

```
[
    'label'   => 'Sejarah Pengambilan',
    'url'     => ['/paket/index-history'],
    'active'  => in_array($this->context->action->id, ['index-history', 'index-search']),
],
```